# How can I export collected metrics data from web application using javamelody

Tags: java-melody

I have my web application in production mode using javamelody APIs, collecting daily metrics for last 2 months. I want to export the collected data metrics from production environment and ship the data to test environment to do report analysis. I see javamelody uses rrd files to save the historical data reports.

Is there any way I can export the historical data reports and import in my local environment web app? I dont want the pdf reports.

Many thanks